# How can I use the blog index within the homepage?

Tags: django, wagtail

I'm new to wagtail and pretty new to django. I'm wondering how to implement the blog that's documented here:

https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/getting_started/tutorial.html

but directly within the home page. Meaning, I'd like the blog index to be the root of the site (like most blogging sites have).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You could just add your blog 'posts' (e.g. BlogPage) as direct children under the home page.

This will mean your blog page URLs will be directly under the root URL.
e.g. `mydomain.com/my-cool-post/`.

Note: Other pages under the home page will share this route area (e.g. `/contact-us/`).

Essentially just follow the steps in the tutorial but ignore the part about the `BlogIndex`. Keep your `BlogPage` model as is and when adding children in the admin UI add them under the home page.

If you want to list all the posts on your `HomePage` template, you can revise the template context to return `blog_pages` similar to the [documentation](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/topics/pages.html?highlight=get_context#customising-template-context).

You can filter a page queryset by [type using `exact_type`](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/reference/pages/queryset_reference.html#wagtail.core.query.PageQuerySet.exact_type). Or, as shown below, you can use `BlogPage.childOf(...)` to query the other way.

Django documentation about [the queryset api](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/).

**`my-app/models.py`**

```py
class HomePage(Page):
    body = RichTextField(blank=True)

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        FieldPanel('body', classname="full"),
    ]

    def get_context(self, request):
        context = super().get_context(request)

        # Add extra variables and return the updated context
        # note: be sure to get the `live` pages so you do not show draft pages
        context['blog_pages'] = BlogPage.objects.child_of(self).live()
        return context
```

**`my-app/templates/home_page.html`**

```html
{{ page.title }}

{% for blog_page in blog_pages %}
    {{ blog_page.title }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks - in this scenario, would I run python manage.py startapp blog as per the instructions? Or simply add the BlogPage model within my-app/models.py?

Comment: That is up to you, if your site is small, you may not need a new app for the `blog` area. If you want to put them in separate apps, you may need to pull in the `BlogPage` model dynamically via [`apps.get_model`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/applications/#django.apps.apps.get_model). But, keeping it simple might be a good start, one app is fine for a while.

Answer (score 0):

Simple, using redirect in urls.py like below code:

```
from django.views.generic import RedirectView
urlpatterns = [
    path(r'^$', RedirectView.as_view(url='/blog/', permanent=False)),
    # pass other paths
]
```

Comment: That's the thing - I don't want to redirect. I don't want the /blog to exist at all. If you go to gizmodo.com it gives a list of blog posts...it doesn't need to redirect to /blog anywhere. I'm hoping I can do that with wagtail.

Comment: so, you can find the blog view out, and path home url to it directly. I think you can figure it out.